# Monitoring private internal URLs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Is there a way to monitor private internal URLs through AWS to monitor health and uptime? Currently using Nagios but need to monitor private URLs. I was thinking of using Cloudwatch Synthetics canary but wanted to see if it was possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, CloudWatch Synthetics Canary is the appropriate service to use. The official documentation includes details on [running the canary in your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_VPC.html) to access private URLs.